# Issue in detecting persons when they are standing closer

Tags: python, object-detection

I am trying to detect number of persons in the image using Python and ImageAI- test2.png and I am using the following code:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
detector = ObjectDetection()
model_path = "yolo.h5"
input_path = 'test2.png'
output_path = "test2_new.png"
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(model_path)
detector.loadModel()
custom_objects=detector.CustomObjects(person=True)
detection = detector.detectCustomObjectsFromImage(custom_objects=custom_objects,     input_image=input_path, output_image_path=output_path, minimum_percentage_probability=20,display_percentage_probability=False,display_object_name=False)

for eachItem in detection:
    print(eachItem["name"] , " : ", eachItem["percentage_probability"])
```

Though we have 9 persons in that image, the above code has identified 7 persons only (please refer test2_new.png). I am getting similar issue when persons are standing very close (or one behind another). 
[test2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WWt3.jpg)
[test2_new.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaUpa.png)

I have also tried to solve this using FasterRCnn and RetinaNet and I am getting same result.

Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to retrain the model taking the failed cases and add them into the model training data so all the cases of interest are addressed.